# VBA "Object Required" Error ONLY WHEN computer is locked

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

My code below scans the provided doc file (sp parameter) and copy over the tables to a sheet named "xxxx" (given in global variable 'shtTableName'.
This code is working perfectly fine when computer is NOT locked. But this code fails to run when screen/computer is locked.

I traced that the issue.. it is with line

```
sht.Paste Range("A1")
```

i tried

```
Acitvesheet.Paste
```

but it throws same error.

I tried every possible thing in Excel vba but none worked,....

on top of this, when it throws error, it is not captured in ErrWord section, it immediately throws the error to the parent error handler of calling procedure....

I cant understand why screen/computer locking can create such an issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Windows 10 Version 1808 Build 10730.20348

Thanks
Gaurav

```
Sub read_word_document(filename As String)

    Dim DOC_PATH As String
    DOC_PATH = filename

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim rng As Range, t As Word.Table
    Dim oData As New DataObject 'object to use the clipboard
    Dim bWordDocObjectCreated As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrWord

        bWordDocObjectCreated = False
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = True
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(DOC_PATH, ReadOnly:=True)
        bWordDocObjectCreated = True 'indicates that object WordDoc has been created and file has been opened

        Set sht = Sheets(shtTableName)
        Set rng = sht.Range("A1")

        For Each t In WordDoc.Tables
            sht.Cells.Delete Shift:=-4162
            sht.Activate
            sht.Range("A1").Select
            t.Range.Copy
            sht.Paste Range("A1")
            'ActiveSheet.Paste
            Exit For 'get only first table
        Next t

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        oData.SetText Text:=Empty 'Clear
        oData.PutInClipboard 'take it to the clipboard to empty it

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        WordDoc.Close False
        WordApp.Quit
        Exit Sub

ErrWord:
        If Not UCase(Err.Description) Like "*CORRUPTED*" And bWordDocObjectCreated = True Then
            Data.SetText Text:=Empty 'Clear
            oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            WordDoc.Close False
        End If

        WordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Try doing it without using `Select` Or `Activate` anywhere. In the block where you report the error the code tries to select a cell. This shouldn't be necessary for writing content to a range. It also shouldn't be necessary to activate the sheet. You instantiate `rng` near the beginning of the code - use that object instead of repeating what is assigned to it. Also, make sure you set the ScreenUpdating to false in both applications - Word and Excel.

Comment: Range("A1") may be using a default object you dont have access to when locked.  try `sht.Paste sht.Range("A1")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but in excel. The solution that worked for me was adding

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the macro. This may or may not work in your case.

Generally speaking, macros that simulate a user's actions e.g copy/pasting, sending keystrokes, cannot be run when the screen is locked - in my experience.

You may need another application to ensure the screen is unlocked before running the macro, or keep the screen unlocked. I have used [Caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) for this purpose successfully.

Comment: I added this code at the very beginning of the execution. It did not make any difference. Thanks for your input.Application.ScreenUpdating = False